# How to calculate the values of a pandas DataFrame column depending on the results of a rolling function from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

A very simple example just for understanding.

**The goal is to calculate the values of a pandas DataFrame column depending on the results of a rolling function from another column.**

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1])    
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA':s, 'POINTS':0})

df
```

[image: DataFrame start]

*Note: I don't even know how to format the Jupyter Notebook results in the Stackoverflow edit window, so I copy and paste the image, I beg your pardon.*

The **DATA** column shows the observed data; the **POINTS** column, initialized to 0, is used to collect the output of a "rolling" function applied to DATA column, as explained in the following.

Set a window = 4

```
nwin = 4
```

Just for the example, **the "rolling" function calculate the max**.

Now let me use a drawing to explain what I need.

[image: Algo flow]

For every iteration, the rolling function calculate the maximum of the data in the window; then the POINT at the same index of the max DATA is incremented by 1.

The final result is:

[image: DataFrame end]

Can you help me with the python code?

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance for your time,
Gilberto

*P.S. Can you also suggest how to copy and paste Jupyter Notebook formatted cell to Stackoverflow edit window? Thank you.*

Comment: Copy the output of `print(df)` in the edit window, and format it all as code (`{}` button in the toolbar). See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: "For every iteration, the rolling function calculate the maximum of the data in the window; then the POINT at the same index of the max DATA is incremented by 1." - I don't understand: isn't this incrementing `POINTS` by `(df.DATA.rolling(4).max() == df.DATA).astype(int)`? It doesn't fit your output example, though.

Comment: @AmiTavory, the way I understand it, the first three rolling windows have their max at index 2, so the value of `POINTS` at index 2 is incremented three times. The fourth rolling window no longer covers index 2, so the algorithm moves on, so to speak. An interesting problem, I'd say...

Comment: @AmiTavory you have understood correctly.

Comment: @IanS Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Gilberto I think you meant IanS.

Comment: Yes I'm very sorry. @IanS understood correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC the explanation by @IanS (thanks again!), you can do

```
In [75]: np.array([df.DATA.rolling(4).max().shift(-i) == df.DATA for i in range(4)]).T.sum(axis=1)
Out[75]: array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0])
```

To update the column:

```
In [78]: df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA':s, 'POINTS':0})

In [79]: df.POINTS += np.array([df.DATA.rolling(4).max().shift(-i) == df.DATA for i in range(4)]).T.sum(axis=1)

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
   DATA  POINTS
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       3
3     2       0
4     1       0
5     2       0
6     3       3
7     2       0
8     1       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AmiTavory ! My Python knowledge is still poor, but your answer help me very much.

Comment: And thank you @IanS for help to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1])    
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA':s, 'POINTS':0})

df.POINTS=df.DATA.rolling(4).max().shift(-1)
df.POINTS=(df.POINTS*(df.POINTS==df.DATA)).fillna(0)
```